# How to change owner of Docker for Windows

Tags: linux, windows, docker

## Environment

- Windows 10 [10.0.15063]
- Docker for Windows Community Edition 17.03.1-ce-win12(12058) stable
- The host is mounted and partitioned into NTFS format

## Command

### host

`docker run -d --volume E:/tmp:/tmp/test --name debian debian:8
docker exec -it debian /bin/bash`

### container

`cd /tmp/test
mkdir abc
ls -l # This line will be shown that root is the owner of abc
useradd hello
chown hello:hello abc
ls -l # This line will be shown that root is still the owner of abc`

## Question

How can I change the owner of mounted directories? or I can't within Windows?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: What actually you want to achieve?

Comment: @JanshairKhan I want to change the owner of folder `abc`

Answer (score 0):

So far, I haven't found a solution in Windows. But I found a way to solve this problem with [data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#add-a-data-volume).